# How do I insert a daterange amongst other placeholder variables in postgresql & express?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, express

I apologize for probably the simplest question, but I am self teaching myself SQL & PostgresSQL by jumping into the deep end (I guess!) and ran across this issue.

I'm trying to insert a large amount of placeholders into a INSERT statement, but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to pass a daterange into the placeholder. Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO campgrounds (campground_name, email_address, address, city, state, zipcode, phone_number, website, number_of_sites,maximum_rv_length, max_amps, description, seasondates, campground_type, region, open_date, close_date) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $5, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12,[$13,$14),$15,$16,$17,$13,$14) RETURNING id
```

In this example, seasondates is a daterange type, and $13 and $14 are the dates I am trying to insert.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Use the function [daterange()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN):

```
INSERT INTO campgrounds (
    campground_name,
    email_address,
    address,
    city,
    STATE,
    zipcode,
    phone_number,
    website,
    number_of_sites,
    maximum_rv_length,
    max_amps,
    description,
    seasondates,
    campground_type,
    region,
    open_date,
    close_date 
)
VALUES
    ( $1, $2, $3, $5, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12,daterange($13,$14,'[)'),$15,$16,$17,$13,$14 
    ) RETURNING ID;
```